# Return an aggregate function as a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently trying to return a series of aggregate functions as percentages. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do it?

Here is the SQL below.

```
SELECT
 et.Term
,count(et.employeeid) as 'Total Enrolled'
,sum(et.retained) as 'Retained'
,sum(et.EnrollButSwitchedDept) as 'EnrollButSwitched'
,sum(et.NotEnrolled) as 'Not Enrolled'
,sum(et.Graduated) as 'Graduated'
--,CAST(sum(et.retained))*100.0 as 'Retained %'
,CAST (((sum(et.retained))*100.0)/(((count (et.EmployeeID)))) as Numeric(10,2) as 'Retained %'

FROM #EnrollmentTypes et

WHERE 1 = 1

GROUP BY et.Term
```

As of right now I'm getting the error below.

```
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.
```

Comment: your error is because youre missing the datatype to which are you casting `CAST(sum(et.retained) as decimal(8,2)) ` for example

Comment: I tried to cast using the datatype numeric and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: the `as` part should be inside the parenthesis of the cast function `CAST ((sum(et.retained)*100.0/count(et.EmployeeID)) as Numeric(10,2) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of a few of the unnecessary parentheses it will be easier to see where the remaining should go. The corrected query that should work:

```
SELECT
 et.Term
,COUNT(et.employeeid) AS 'Total Enrolled'
,SUM(et.retained) AS 'Retained'
,SUM(et.EnrollButSwitchedDept) AS 'EnrollButSwitched'
,SUM(et.NotEnrolled) AS 'Not Enrolled'
,SUM(et.Graduated) AS 'Graduated'
,CAST(SUM(et.retained) * 100.0 / COUNT(et.EmployeeID) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS 'Retained %'
FROM #EnrollmentTypes et
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY et.Term
```